# Redirecting WordPress 4.x to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I support a WordPress 4.x site, lifering.org, which has a test site, lifering.org/sitetest, and I'm experimenting on the test site to try to do a redirect to all HTTPS for the whole site.  The production site has an SSL certificate.  The test site is installed in a subdirectory on the production site. First of all, can I even test HTTPS on the test site, which doesn't have a cert dedicated to it?  I'd really like not to have to test this on the live site, which is heavily used.

Second, I was planning to use .htaccess redirect.  The redirect code which seems to be recommended in the sources I've checked is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But my existing .htaccess file contains this:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# Begin directory fix
Options All +Indexes 
# END directory fix
```

The first If module is for a plugin we use, but since it doesn't contain a rewrite statement I don't care.

I know you aren't supposed to have more than one *RewriteEngine On* statement in an .htaccess file.  I also know that the one in the If module (which is required for WordPress permalinks in versions later than 3.0) will not necessarily execute every time.  Should I insert the HTTPS redirect code after the *RewriteEngine On* statement inside the If module (which seems worse the more I think about it), or put it at the top of the file, with its own *RewriteEngine On*?  If I have a universal *RewriteEngine On* statement, do I need the one in the If module?

Comment: The `[L]` flag says it's the last rule to be processed. I'd suggest removing that flag from your redirect rule and then putting it above the Wordpress one. Keep it inside the `IfModule` check, and yes you only need to enable rewriting once.

Comment: Thanks, miken32, I'll try that.